# How to copy the fetching files of $(bazel info output_base)/external/* to another machine?

Tags: bazel

I can compile the project successfully via bazel, also fetch the third_party files using http-archive.
However, I need to compile the same project in another machine, but in this machine i don't   want to fetch the third_party files because this machine not connected to the Internet.

And I want to reuse the .cache/xx/external/* files, how to do it?

Comment: You should try implement the remote cache https://bazel.build/docs/remote-caching for your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line flag `--distdir=<a path>` to provide to Bazel with additional places to search for archives before accessing the network to download them. Check also the Bazel [documentation about this flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--distdir).

Consider the documentation also about [Running Bazel in an airgapped environment](https://bazel.build/docs/build#running-bazel-airgapped).

Comment: There's also this advice on how to run bazel itself without network access: https://bazel.build/docs/build#running-bazel-airgapped

Comment: @ahumesky I added the link to my answer! Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

@ahumesky, @Vertexwahn, thanks, it works.

1. bazel sync --experimental_repository_resolved_file=resolved.bzl ,
   This resolved.bzl is a json file
2. wget curls or curl of the resolved.bzl and download the files into the `$(your directory)`
3. in the .bazel.rc, add the command "common --distdir=`$(your directory)` "

it will works.